# Why Ext.getCmp is a bad practice? Can be replaced with itemId in all scenarios?

Tags: extjs4

I´ve been using ExtJS for a while and always used "Ext.getCmp" when instanciating components, but most of the time I read that it´s a bad practice and that "itemId" should be used instead, so I´d like to know why is "itemId" better than "Ext.getCmp" and if can be used always.
Additionally I´ve encounter examples where i´m not able (or don´t know how) to use "itemId".
Example:
I can set the disabled property of a button with "Ext.getCmp":

```
    Ext.getCmp('btnMyButton').setDisabled(true);
```

But with "itemId" I get error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
    btnMyButton.setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get button element by item id then call the setDisabled.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnMyButton').setDisabled(true);
```

You can refer below link to understand more on id vs itemId

https://vimeo.com/14816550